# Caixas de seleção com Banco de Dados php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Boa tarde.

Peço desde agora pra que relevem minha pouco experiencia em programação. Caso minha pergunta não esteja bem encaixada com o tema que eu vou apresentar, peço que me desculpem. Peço a ajuda e colaboração de vocês.

Estou fazendo um projeto de garagem em que eu tenho duas caixas de seleção. Uma que seleciona o veiculo pela placa e outra de motorista que seleciona pelo nome. Segue a baixo o layout

[image: imagem1]

Quando eu seleciono o veículo, ele busca no banco de dados todos os dados do próprio. Os campos dos quais ele depositará os dados que serão buscados a partir do item selecionado estão contornados pelas linhas vermelhas.

A caixa de seleção do funcionário é o mesmo dilema, porém, são os campos da linha verde.

Basicamente, eu seleciono a placa do veículo / nome do motorista e assim é feita uma query que usa a placa ou o nome do motorista no Where. Vou tentar explicar mais detalhadamente:

Ao selecionar o item, ele vai "recarregar" a página e vai trazer o valor selecionado pelo "$_POST", como:

Caixa de seleção de placas:

```
    <select id="placas" name="placa" onclick="if (this.value != ''){this.form.submit()};">
        <option value="">- PLACAS -</option>
    <?php
        $i=0; 
        while(odbc_fetch_row($sql))
            { 
                $i++;
            $placa=odbc_result($sql,"PLACA");
    ?>                      
            <option value="<?php echo $placa; ?>" ><?php echo $placa; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
    </select>

&nbsp;

$_POST: 

    $var = $_POST['placa'];
```

A partir desse ponto, ele usará a variável "$var" para fazer o filtro na query. Como:

```
    $sql1 =  odbc_exec($conn1," SELECT  ID_FLASHPT AS 'ID', 
                                                    NOME_VEICULO AS 'NOME',
                                                    PLACA_VEICULO AS 'PLACAS',
                                                    MARCA_VEICULO AS 'MARCA',
                                                    QUILMT_VEICULO AS 'QUILOMETRO',
                                                    DOCMT_VEICULO AS 'DOCUMENTO',
                                                    COR_VEICULO AS 'COR',
                                                    COMBTVL_VEICULO AS 'COMBUSTIVEL',
                                                    ANO_MODL_VEICULO AS 'MODELO',
                                                    ANO_FABRC_VEICULO AS 'FABRICACAO',
                                                    OBS_VEICULO AS 'OBS'
                                        FROM        FLASHPT
                                        WHERE   PLACA_VEICULO = '$var'");

&nbsp;
```

No caso seria feito um filtro a partir da variável '$placa' ou '$motorista' presente no Where da Query.

Até ai, funciona.
Ao selecionar a opção, ele "recarregará" a página e trará o valor selecionado na caixa de seleção da placa pelo $_POST e grava em uma variável (nesse caso, a "$var") e assim usa essa variável para fazer a Query e armazena os valores do filtro em variáveis que serão passadas para os inputs. Como:

Valores que serão filtrados a partir da "$var" e armazenados em variáveis para que sejam passados para um input, logo após.

```
    $nome=odbc_result($sql1,"NOME");
    $marc=odbc_result($sql1,"MARCA");
    $quil=odbc_result($sql1,"QUILOMETRO");
    $doc=odbc_result($sql1,"DOCUMENTO");
    $cor=odbc_result($sql1,"COR");
    $comb=odbc_result($sql1,"COMBUSTIVEL");
    $mod=odbc_result($sql1,"MODELO");
    $fab=odbc_result($sql1,"FABRICACAO");
    $placas=odbc_result($sql1,"PLACAS");
    $obsveiculo=odbc_result($sql1,"OBS");

&nbsp;
```

Inputs:
Esses inputs são os circulados pelas linhas vermelhas ou verdes, na imagem presente logo a cima.

```
    <input type="text" maxlength="10" minlength="8" required placeholder="Placa" disabled style="font-size: 15pt;" value="<?php echo $placas ?>" name="placaveiculo">

&nbsp;
```

Porém, quando eu seleciono a placa e assim recarrega a página trazendo os valores que ficam nos inputs circulados em vermelho (do mesmo jeito que esta na imagem logo a cima) e depois vou selecionar o motorista, ao recarregar a pagina novamente para trazer dessa vez os dados do motorista, ele traz os dados do motorista corretamente, porém, ele apaga os dados do veiculo e assim sucessivamente.

Peço que me ajudem, caso eu não tenha tido clareza na minha duvida, me perguntem que eu tento especificar melhor minha explicação

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score -1):

Você terá que trabalhar com `$_GET` `IF(ISSET())`
Ao meu ver iria ficar mais ou menos assim.

```
if(isset($_GET['Placa']) AND isset($_GET['Motorista'])){
$placa=$_GET['placa'];
$motorista=$_GET['Motorista'];
Aqui vc faz o Sqqlect
exemple
select id from ex where motorista =$motorista and placa=$placa
}elseif(isset($_GET['Placa'])){
$placa=$_GET['placa'];
Aqui vc faz o Sqqlect
exemple
select id from ex where  placa=$placa
}esleif(isset($_GET['Motorista'])){
$motorista=$_GET['Motorista'];
Aqui vc faz o Sqqlect
exemple
select id from ex where motorista =$motorista 
}else{}
```